# apt-get install -f suggests removing 80 packages

Tags: apt, package-management, skype

I am trying to install Skype on my Ubuntu 16.04 (64bit) but I am having a hard time. After running the following to try and install it:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo dpkg -i skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb
sudo apt-get -f install
```

I get the message shown below, which suggests removing 79 packages. I have no clue why this is happening, any help would be appreciated.

```
sudo apt-get -f install 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  adium-theme-ubuntu apturl apturl-common gcc-6-base:i386
  gnome-software-common guile-2.0-libs libasound2:i386 libasyncns0:i386
  libavahi-common-data:i386 libavahi-common3:i386 libbsd0:i386 libc6:i386
  libcap2:i386 libcdparanoia0:i386 libcomerr2:i386 libedataserverui-1.2-1
  libedit2:i386 libelf1:i386 libffi6:i386 libflac8:i386 libfreetype6:i386
  libgc1c2 libgcc1:i386 libglapi-mesa:i386 libgmp10:i386 libgpg-error0:i386
  libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 libhogweed4:i386 libice6:i386 libjbig0:i386
  libjpeg-turbo8:i386 libjpeg8:i386 libjson-c2:i386 libk5crypto3:i386
  libkeyutils1:i386 libkrb5-3:i386 libkrb5support0:i386 liblcms2-2:i386
  liblzma5:i386 libmng2:i386 libnettle6:i386 libogg0:i386 libopus0:i386
  liborc-0.4-0:i386 liborcus-0.10-0v5 libp11-kit0:i386 libpciaccess0:i386
  libpcre3:i386 libpng12-0:i386 libpoppler-qt4-4 libqt5x11extras5
  libsamplerate0:i386 libselinux1:i386 libsndfile1:i386 libspeexdsp1:i386
  libsqlite3-0:i386 libssl1.0.0:i386 libtheora0:i386 libtiff5:i386
  libtinfo5:i386 libvisual-0.4-0:i386 libvorbis0a:i386 libvorbisenc2:i386
  libwrap0:i386 libx11-6:i386 libx11-xcb1:i386 libxau6:i386 libxcb-dri2-0:i386
  libxcb-dri3-0:i386 libxcb-glx0:i386 libxcb-present0:i386 libxcb-sync1:i386
  libxcb1:i386 libxdamage1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386 libxfixes3:i386
  libxi6:i386 libxrender1:i386 libxshmfence1:i386 libxss1:i386 libxv1:i386
  libxxf86vm1:i386 mysql-common squashfs-tools ubuntu-wallpapers
  ubuntu-wallpapers-xenial zlib1g:i386
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  gcc-6-base:i386 libc6:i386 libgcc1:i386 libssl1.0.0:i386 libx11-6:i386
  libxau6:i386 libxcb1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386 libxss1:i386
  libxv1:i386
Suggested packages:
  glibc-doc:i386 locales:i386
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  aisleriot appstream bamfdaemon brltty compiz compiz-gnome deja-dup eog
  file-roller firefox flashplugin-installer fwupd gdb gimp git gnome-calendar
  gnome-software gstreamer1.0-alsa gstreamer1.0-fluendo-mp3 gstreamer1.0-libav
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-faad
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-videoparsers gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly-amr gstreamer1.0-tools
  gtk2-engines-murrine gvfs-bin gvfs-fuse indicator-printers intel-gpu-tools
  kerneloops-daemon libappstream3 libbabeltrace-ctf1 libbabeltrace1
  libchromaprint0 libcompizconfig0 libdfu1 libfwupd1 libgimp2.0
  libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libgtkspell3-3-0 libmagickcore-6.q16-2-extra
  libmetacity-private3a libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer libreoffice-calc
  libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk libreoffice-ogltrans libreoffice-pdfimport
  light-themes nautilus-share notify-osd plymouth-label
  plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo printer-driver-brlaser python-gtk2 r-cran-xml
  simple-scan skype:i386 snapd system-config-printer-udev texstudio-qt4
  thermald touchegg ubuntu-artwork ubuntu-core-launcher ubuntu-desktop
  ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk ubuntu-software unity unity-lens-applications
  update-manager update-notifier virtualbox-5.1 whoopsie
  xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg-video-qxl
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gcc-6-base:i386 libc6:i386 libgcc1:i386 libssl1.0.0:i386 libx11-6:i386
  libxau6:i386 libxcb1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386 libxss1:i386
  libxv1:i386
0 upgraded, 11 newly installed, 79 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
```

Edit: 
I don't know if this helps, but if I remove skype:i386 after this, and then run apt-get -f install, I get no errors:

```
sudo apt-get -f install 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

**Edit**: Some troubleshooting which helped with the solution (thanks @user.dz !)

**Attempt 1**

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture amd64
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo dpkg -i skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb
```

Still getting errors:
`dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of skype:i386`, plus a list of libs. 
Also, it creates the 'Error: BrokenCount>0' on Ubuntu

**Attempt 2**

```
apt-cache policy libqt4-dbus:i386
```

Still, errors: http://pastebin.com/ijCAJAXf

**Attempt 3: gdebi**

Installed gdebi, tried:
    sudo gdebi --o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb

But again, dependency problems persist: http://pastebin.com/pP2k1xxF

**Attempt 4**

So after checking

```
apt-cache policy libqt4-dbus:i386
```

With the following result: http://pastebin.com/ijCAJAXf, tried installing the missing dependency

```
sudo apt-get install libqt4-dbus:i386
```

But still getting the unmet dependencies error:

```
libqt4-dbus:i386 : Depends: libqtdbus4:i386 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed 
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

**Attempt 5: Aptitude and extra troubleshooting**

Install aptitude, and tried installing the missing dependency with it (aptitude is better at working with dependencies)

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
echo q | aptitude -s install libqtdbus4:i386
```

It still didn't manage to install it, http://pastebin.com/CNfN0dEp

The output of

```
apt-get -s -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes install libqtdbus4:i386
```

is the one in here: http://pastebin.com/8yJSXtue

And also the output of rdepends

```
sudo apt-get install apt-rdepends
apt-cache policy $(apt-rdepends libqt4-dbus:i386 2>/dev/null | grep "^[a-zA-Z]" | sort | paste -s -d" ")
```

http://pastebin.com/jFDVerhr

Comment: Precise is 12.04, do you can't install that Skype package; remove it.

Comment: Try `sudo dpkg --add-architecture amd64; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get autoremove; sudo apt-get upgrade; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade; 
sudo dpkg -i skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb`

Comment: @user.dz Tried it, not working either. I still get an error: `dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of skype:i386`, plus a list of libs. Moreover, it creates the `'Error: BrokenCount>0'`

Comment: Install `gdebi` then post the output of `sudo gdebi --o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb`

Comment: @user.dz Thanks for your help :) This is what I get from it: http://pastebin.com/pP2k1xxF

Comment: Could you add output of `apt-cache policy libqt4-dbus:i386`

Comment: @fkraiem , that's the only package offered by skype official site for Ubuntu 12.04 & later.

Comment: @user.dz There you go: http://pastebin.com/ijCAJAXf

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48576/discussion-between-user-dz-and-j-mac).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some (a lot of actually) help from @user.dz, I could find out the problem.

The problem was here:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
libdbus-1-3 : Breaks: libdbus-1-3:i386 (!= 1.10.6-1ubuntu3.1) but 1.10.6-1ubuntu3 is to be installed. 
libdbus-1-3:i386 : Breaks: libdbus-1-3 (!= 1.10.6-1ubuntu3) but 1.10.6-1ubuntu3.1 is installed. 
libsystemd0 : Breaks: libsystemd0:i386 (!= 229-4ubuntu10) but 229-4ubuntu4 is to be installed. 
libsystemd0:i386 : Breaks: libsystemd0 (!= 229-4ubuntu4) but 229-4ubuntu10 is installed. 
gcc-5-base : Breaks: gcc-5-base:i386 (!= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2) but 5.3.1-14ubuntu2 is to be installed. 
gcc-5-base:i386 : Breaks: gcc-5-base (!= 5.3.1-14ubuntu2) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2 is installed. 
libgcrypt20 : Breaks: libgcrypt20:i386 (!= 1.6.5-2ubuntu0.2) but 1.6.5-2 is to be installed. 
libgcrypt20:i386 : Breaks: libgcrypt20 (!= 1.6.5-2) but 1.6.5-2ubuntu0.2 is installed. 
libstdc++6 : Breaks: libstdc++6:i386 (!= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2) but 5.3.1-14ubuntu2 is to be installed. 
libstdc++6:i386 : Breaks: libstdc++6 (!= 5.3.1-14ubuntu2) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2 is installed. 
libglib2.0-0 : Breaks: libglib2.0-0:i386 (!= 2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1) but 2.48.0-1ubuntu4 is to be installed. 
libglib2.0-0:i386 : Breaks: libglib2.0-0 (!= 2.48.0-1ubuntu4) but 2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1 is installed.
```

Notice how each package (except for libdbus-1-3 (amd64)) has conflict with its libdbus-1-3:i386
(i386 component), because they should be the same version. `apt-get` does not solve some cases that need downgrade of a package, however,`aptitude` does provide such advanced solution.

Trying

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Did not produce any output `(0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded)`, and I couldn't install the missing dependency manually either, as `sudo apt-get install libdbus-1-3=1.10.6-1ubuntu3.1 libdbus-1-3:i386=1.10.6-1ubuntu3.1` returned `E: Version '1.10.6-1ubuntu3.1' for 'libdbus-1-3:i386' was not found`.

And then, `apt-cache policy libdbus-1-3:i386` returned

```
libdbus-1-3:i386: 
Installed: (none) 
Candidate: 1.10.6-1ubuntu3 
Version table: 
1.10.6-1ubuntu3 500 
500 archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
```

Letting us know that the update and security repositories weren't enabled. The solution was to enable them and install the missing dependency with aptitude.

## Solution

**1. Enable security & updates repositories**

In System Settings>Software and Updates>Updates, enable both:
[image: Enable security & updates repos]

**2. Update and dist-upgrade**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

**3. Install the missing dependency**

```
sudo aptitude -s install libqtdbus4:i386
```

**4. Install Skype!**

```
sudo aptitude install skype
```

I hope this can help someone, thanks @user.dz again :)